# App crashes when data for two entities are saved on different classes and passed to other class in core data

Tags: ios, core-data, relationships

Hi I am new to core data and working on relationships for first time.I have two tables i.e.School and Book 
School and Book has one to many relationship

I am not getting the cause for this exception.Kindly help me to resolve it by giving your suggestions.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check my answer, if you face problem, please ask in comments

Comment: Does the answer solve your problem?

Comment: No,just check the relationship that I have added as image.

Comment: Image shows that you have one to many relationship, see my updated answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for crash is this line

```
[school setValue:book forKey:@"books"];
```

Comment: Sir,the relationship that I have added is correct ,I can't change it ..maybe there is some problem in implementing the code and I need ur help in fixing that.

Comment: @Prez I updated the answer please check, if face problem, ask

Comment: @Prez Good work, If you still have not understood anything please ask, happy coding